# Implementing a docs search for multiple docs sites

Tags: search, documentation

We have many different documentation sites and I would like to search a keyword across all of these sites. How can I do that?

I already thought about implementing a simple web scraper, but this seems like a very ugly solution.

An alternative may be to use Elasticsearch and somehow point it to the different doc repos.

Are there better suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Algolia is the absolute best solution that I can think of. There's also Typesense and Meilisearch of course.

Algolia is meant specifically for situations like yours, so it even comes with a crawler.
`https://www.algolia.com/products/search-and-discovery/crawler/`

`https://www.algolia.com/`

`https://typesense.org/`

`https://www.meilisearch.com/`

Here's a fun page comparing them (probably a little biased in Typesense's favor)
`https://typesense.org/typesense-vs-algolia-vs-elasticsearch-vs-meilisearch/`

Here are some example sites that use Algolia Search

`https://developers.cloudflare.com/`

`https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/`

`https://reactjs.org/`

`https://hn.algolia.com/`

If you personally are just trying to search for a keyword, as long as they're indexed by Google, you can always search with the format `site:{domain} "keyword"`

Comment: Thank you. I will check out algolia in the coming days

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout Meilisearch for your use case. Meilisearch is a Rust based and open sourced search engine.

Meilisearch comes with a document scraper tool ( https://github.com/meilisearch/docs-scraper ) that can scrape content and then also index it.

While using it you need to define what exact content you are searching for in the configuration file for the scraper tool. And then you can run the tool using Docker.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I like the idea of Meilisearch, but I constantly get connection refused when trying to connect against my localhost